# SQL populating leading rows with conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by, case, window-functions

I have a table like below

[image]

if column `condition` is populated then for all rows after that row, populate column `new` column with value `flag` if `other condition` column contains `x` and `episode start` and `episode end` for that row matches with the earlier closest row where `condition` column contains `yes`

final output:

```
index   name    condition   episode_start   Episode_end other_condition  value     new
1         a                           11       12           
2         a                            1        2           
3         a          yes               1        2           
4         a                            1        2           
5         a                            1        2              x          f       flag
6         a                            3        4              b          cc
```

---

#update1 below suggested answer works.

But not sure how to make this change

In the current case, we are looking for specific conditions in rows that come after the row where column `condition`=`yes`

instead of looking at previous rows, is there a way to look at rows that come after the current row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow this correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case when other_condition = 'x'
        and max(condition) over(partition by episode_start, episode_end order by index) is not null
    then 'flag'
    end as newcol
from mytable t
```

Once a non-`null` `condition` is met, this flags all subsequent rows have the same `episode_start` and `episode_end` and a non-`null` value in `other_condition`.

Comment: how are you checking that `condition` column is populated in a row BEFORE the current row?

Comment: and is there a way to check if the `condition` column is populated with `yes` rather than `not null`?

Comment: @user2543622: the window max does that. Because of the `order by` clause, only preceding rows are taken into account (up until the current row, included).

Comment: @user2543622: so, `and max(...) over(...) = 'yes'`

Comment: does window max function work because we are processing one row at a time?

Comment: @user2543622: basically, just change the `order by` clause of the window `max()` to `order by index desc`. That said, you should not be changing the question after answers were posted. If you have a new question, it should be asked as *a new question*.